# get all ADusers with numeric SamAccountName

Tags: powershell, filter

How can I get  all ADusers with numeric SamAccountName. 
if SamAccountName  include letter then I don't need it.

```
$num = Get-AdUser -Filter "SamAccountName  -like [integer]"  -Properties postalCode, postOfficeBox, SamAccountName, Enabled
```

Comment: I believe you should be able to minimize your result set by using an LDAP filter similar to: "(&(sAMAccountName>=0)(sAMAccountName<=9*))".  If you're just interested in user objects, and want a minor speed boost, use: "(&(sAMAccountName>=0)(sAMAccountName<=9*)(sAMAccountType=805306368))".  Optionally, you may be able to include 26 other 'sAMAccountName doesn't contain a letter' groups, but then you'd probably need more to filter-out symbols (eg, hyphens, underscores), as well.  Better to handle the result set with post-processing, and use a minimal/manageable LDAP filter, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

With the `-Filter` you cannot test if a SamAccountName is made up of only digits and you will have to use the `Where-Object` clause for that using the regex `-math` operator.

```
$users = Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties PostalCode, POBox, SamAccountName, Enabled | 
         Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -match '^\d+$' }
```

Comment: And if I use LDAPFILTER I can test it  ? I don't want get all users and then filtering them. I want it fast. like this ''' $users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(SamAccountName='\d+')" ''' thank you

Comment: @Ivan Nope, both the LDAP and ADSI filters do not allow you to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you cannot use `-Filter` to concisely complete your query, you can use `-Filter` to speed up your query times before piping to `Where-Object`:

```
$Params = @{ Properties = 'postalCode','postOfficeBox','SamAccountName','Enabled'
         Filter = "samaccountname -like '" + (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 -join "*' -or samaccountname -like '") + "'"
          }

Get-AdUser @Params | Where SamAccountName -match '^\d+$'
```

The idea is to only find objects with `samaccountname` beginning with a digit before sending to `Where-Object`, which will display only accounts that have all digits for the property value. This will significantly speed up the query times if you only have a small percentage of accounts that begin with a digit.